# reusable traversal components not always working with gremlin

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I'm trying to create reusable components for my traversals using gremlin python by putting traversal components into functions and I'm running into a problem where some of the traversal components aren't working correctly.

As setup I'm running gremlin server using the docker container with the configuration file loading in the modern graph from the [github repo](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server-modern.yaml)

```
docker run -p 8182:8182 tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.4.6 conf/gremlin-server-modern.yaml
```

My test python code looks like the following:

```
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

def connect_gremlin(endpoint='ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'):
    return traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection(endpoint,'g'))

def n():
    return __.values('name')

def r():
    return __.range(2,4)

g = connect_gremlin()

# works as expected
g.V().map(n()).toList()

# returns an empty list
g.V().map(n()).filter(r()).toList()

# but using range step directly works as expected
g.V().map(n()).range(2,4).toList()
```

I can successfully move the `values` step into a function but when I try to do the same thing with the `range` step it returns an empty list rather than the 2nd through 4th items. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` step is intended to map the state of each traverser to a new state. In the context of a single traverser a `range` starting anywhere but zero is not going to do what you expect.

Here are some examples using Python:

```
>>> g.V().map(__.range(0,1)).limit(5).toList()
[v[1400], v[1401], v[1402], v[1403], v[1404]]

>>> g.V().map(__.range(0,2)).limit(5).toList()
[v[1400], v[1401], v[1402], v[1403], v[1404]]

>>> g.V().map(__.range(1,2)).limit(5).toList()
[]
```

This is why the `values` step works inside a `map` step and `range` does not.

Rather than inject code using a `map` step why not just incrementally add to the traversal and then iterate it when complete?

Comment: I guess if you absolutely had to use `map()` in this fashion you would have to `fold()` and then `range(local)` like: `g.V().fold().map(range(local,2,4))` but that's not so good as it will realize the entire stream to a `List` just to slice it.

Comment: My real use can is a bit more complicated where I want to have several traversal steps that I want to "mixin" to a larger traversal. A common pattern that I'm doing in my traversals is something like `order().by(a).range(x, y)`, so I was hoping there was a way to wrap them up into functions.